# How to center row with a three columns row in a container-fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have [this layout](http://bassfunk.meteor.com/), based on twitter bootstrap.
It looks centered in [narrow screens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z00rtoedsyfdxbb/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-12-01%2012.24.42.png?dl=0)

[image]

but [totally not centered on more wider screens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o471re4t3m402n5/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-12-01%2012.26.24.png?dl=0)

[image]

In html it basically looks like that:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<!-- This row is perfectly centered -->
      <div class="row header center-block">
        <div class="logo col-md-12 col-lg-12 center-block text-center">
          <img src="logo.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>


<!-- This row needs to be centered -->
      <div class="row content center-block text-center">

<!-- first column with five images. It should be 3 images in a row in narrow screens and 4 in wider screens -->
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 scene itemlist center-block text-center">
          <div class="row scene-header">
            <img src="scene.jpg">
          </div> 

          <div class="row scene-elements">

                <div class="scene-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/ouImJ3j.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="scene-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/6H9PBdO.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="scene-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/S731TrW.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="scene-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/tEj2TzR.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="scene-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/j0fUzW3.jpg">
                </div>
          </div>

        </div>

<!-- Middle row with text. This row needs to have bigger left and right margins on wider screen -->

<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 info center-block text-center">


    <div class="infoblock">
        <div class="row info-header">
            MEFJUS
         </div> 
         <div class="row info-elements">


            <p class="link"><a target="_blank" href="https://soundcloud.com/mefjus">SOUNDCLOUD</a></p>  



            <p class="link"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/mefjus">FACEBOOK</a></p>  



            <p class="link"><a target="_blank" href="http://vk.com/the_upbeats">VK</a></p>  



         </div> 
     </div>

        </div>

<!-- seconf column with five images. It should be 3 images in a row in narrow screens and 4 in wider screens -->
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 our itemlist center-block text-center">
          <div class="row our-header">
            <img src="our.jpg">
          </div> 

          <div class="row our-elements">

                <div class="our-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/IxrgHax.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="our-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/X3roxXK.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="our-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/LH8N8uH.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="our-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/zb3dARv.jpg">
                </div>

                <div class="our-element">
                    <img class="clickimg" src="http://i.imgur.com/rDDkie8.jpg">
                </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <footer class="footer text-center"></footer>

    </div> <!-- /container --></body>
```

I need the `.content` row to be centered as the `.header` row, but `.center-block` and `.text-center` don't work here as they do with the logo. 
As well I need first and third columns to have 3 imager per row on narrow screens and 4 images per row on wider screens. As well, I would like to add some margins from the left and right for middle `.info` column.

What should I do? I'm sorry for so many questions, I'm new in this.

**UPD**
[JSFIDDLE of a layout](http://jsfiddle.net/zahn56wn/)
[ORIGINAL](http://bassfunk.meteor.com/)

Comment: please provide the css / a demo (jsfiddle for example) for this

Comment: yes do you h ave any css and a demo?

Comment: Put `col-lg-offset-1` in the first column. This will shift all columns to the right by 1 column. You may also need to do the same for `md`.

Comment: you can see it deployded over here http://bassfunk.meteor.com/

Comment: @jbutler483 Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zahn56wn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your layout to below `div` widths

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 row content center-block text-center">
          <!-- ^^^^---added md and lg classes here -->
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 scene itemlist center-block text-center"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 info center-block text-center"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 our itemlist center-block text-center"></div>

</div>
```

**Issue(s) :**

1. your have not defined the `md / lg` for the container div which holds the 3 childs divs
2. you are setting un-equal `offset` values for left and right childs - this is causing markup to behave differently in different view port
3. just a thought - *you can disagree* - putting `center-block` in child divs is a waste, just place it on parent!

---

please note `itemlist` has fixed width which distorts the alignment, remove it and all would be good! :)

Comment: can you give a screen shot...please?? :)

Comment: Screenshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/1pqcf7ribtj7zid/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-12-01%2013.10.40.png?dl=0

Comment: @Maay : hmmm, that `bassfunk` logo on the top - *circular one* -  is also moving to the right....it is not in the 3 div markup still its loosing the layout....noticed that?

Comment: Yes, there is two rows and the row with one column (logo) is centered perfectly, but the three columns row is not

Comment: @Maay : so you are saying that, the image you gave above, *bassfunk* logo is centered correctly? I thought it has moved to right!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65947/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-maay).